# Can I save a function's arguments in Matlab to reuse in another function?

Tags: function, matlab, arguments

I am using the topoplot function in Matlab as follows:

```
topoplot(DATA, channels, ...
    'maplimits',  topoYlim, 'electrodes', 'on', 'emarker', {'.','k',[6],1}, ...
    'whitebk', 'on', 'style', 'both', 'shading', 'interp', 'drawaxis', 'off', ...
    'numcontour', [0]);
```

The problem is that I have to use this function several times in different parts of the script.
That really makes the script unnecessarily bulky and difficult to read.

Is there a way to save all the arguments in a variable (like a structure) so that I can just call something like:

```
topoplot(DATA, options)
```

P.S.
I have tried something like:

```
options = splitvars(table(NaN(1,6)));
options.Var1_1 = 'maplimits'
options.Var1_2 = [-1 1]
options.Var1_3 = 'electrodes'
options.Var1_4 = 'on'
options.Var1_5 = 'emarker'
options.Var1_6 = {'.','k',[6],1}
```

but it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance

This is my suboptimal solution.
I have created a separate function as follows:

```
    function makeTopoplot(dataToPlot, channelsToUse, topoYlim)
             topoplot(dataToPlot, channelsToUse, 'maplimits', topoYlim,
             'electrodes', 'on', 'emarker', {'.','k',[6],1}, ...
             'whitebk', 'on', 'style', 'both', 'shading', 'interp',
             'drawaxis', 'off', 'numcontour', [0]);
    end
```

Again, I would have preferred something without creating an external function, but didn't manage yet...

Answer (score 2):

Other than @Cris's suggestion (which works perfectly of course), another option is to make a [local function in your script file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html) that has all the options. Your script file then looks like this:

```
data1 = ...;
myTopoplot(data1, channels);
data2 = ...;
myTopoplot(data2, channels);

% Wrapper around TOPOPLOT to set up common arguments
function myTopoplot(data, channels)
topoYlim = ...;
topoplot(data, channels, ...
    'maplimits',  topoYlim, 'electrodes', 'on', 'emarker', {'.','k',[6],1}, ...
    'whitebk', 'on', 'style', 'both', 'shading', 'interp', 'drawaxis', 'off', ...
    'numcontour', [0]);
end
```

In some cases this can be easier to follow than having a `cell` array of common options.

Comment: Sorry for the very late answer.
I had tried something similar to Cris's suggestion and I've also tried his implementation. Unfortunately, it gives me an error (sry, I tried this too long ago, cannot recall the error).

I had also tried something similar to Edric's solution, in the end that's what I used, although not optimal...I will edit my question to include my suboptimal solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can store the arguments in a cell array as follows:

```matlab
arguments = {
    'maplimits',  topoYlim, 'electrodes', 'on', 'emarker', {'.','k',[6],1}, ...
    'whitebk', 'on', 'style', 'both', 'shading', 'interp', 'drawaxis', 'off', ...
    'numcontour', [0]
};
```

And then use them in the function call as follows:

```matlab
topoplot(DATA, channels, arguments{:});
```

`arguments{:}` generates a comma-separated list with all the contents of the cell array. It is the same as typing `arguments{1}, arguments{2}, arguments{3}, ...`.